# Comparing unix timestamp with date in Django ORM

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm, unix-timestamp, python-datetime

I am trying to fetch all records from a table on a particular date.

My url.py code is :

```
 url(r'^jobs/date/?P<date>.*',RunningJobsListApiView.as_view()),
```

Here is the code of my view to get all the records from the table.

```
class RunningJobsListApiView(generics.ListAPIView):
        queryset = LinuxJobTable.objects.annotate(status=Case(When(state=3, then=Value('Completed')),When(state=5, then=Value('Failed')),When(state=1, then=Value('Running')),default=Value('Unknown'),output_field=CharField(),),)
        serializer_class = JobInfoSerializer
```

Now, I want to filter the jobs for the particular date in url. But In my database date is in UNIX timestamp format(ie.1530773247).

How can I compare DateFormat(mm-dd-yyyy) with UNIX timestamp format saved in DB?

Comment: I guess the easy way would be to calculate unix-timestamp for day start and day end and apply a between filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a UNIX timestamp from a string date representation, you first need to convert the string to a Python `datetime` with [`strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime), and then call the [`timestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) method on it. But since a single day comprises a range of timestamps, you need to do a [`range`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range) query between the start of the target day and the start of the next day.

Something like:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

target_day = datetime.strptime(date, "%m-%d-%Y")
next_day = target_day + timedelta(days=1)
queryset = LinuxJobTable.objects.filter(timestamp__range=(
    int(target_day.timestamp()), 
    int(next_day.timestamp()) - 1  # since range is inclusive
))
```